# how to style the body tag with tailwind.css in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, create-react-app

I recently started with Create-react-app and TailwindCSS and I wanted to change the background of the whole page. couldn't find a way to style the  tag

I tried adding my own style in the index.css file like this

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

but still didn't work, seems that it's overriden by tailwinds styles
is there some way to style the body tag?

Comment: Did you try the `bg` property in Tailwind? Like if you want to change background of entire app to black, you can try to add App component's className to this: `bg-black`

Comment: I guess you can surround everything inside the app component with an extra div and style it, but it wouls be nicer to just be able to style the entire body as a whole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TailwindCSS you can just edit the styles of the `body` tag by adding it to `@layer base` and using the `@apply` keyword to add styles from TailwindCSS. Example:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  body {
    @apply bg-black
  }
}
```